Как с помощью Chocolatey установить PowerToys в определенную директорию?
Я хочу создать .config файл в котором укажу какие программы и куда установить, потому что планирую переустановить операционную систему. Chocolatey позволяет с помощью параметра installArguments передавать значения родному установщику. Например если установщик MSI, то для указание папки достаточно указать installArguments='INSTALLDIR="D:\MyPath"'. Если NSIS то installArguments='/D=D:\MyPath'.
Но я не могу понять какой установщик использует PowerToys и как этому установщику передать куда надо установить программу с помощью Chocolatey. (я знаю что у Chocolatey есть платная версия где есть параметр с помощью которого можно передавать куда установить программу, но это не мой случай)

winget, почему вы им не пользуетесь? https://winget.run/pkg/Microsoft/PowerToys
